# Need help fixing errors on a Java Project

Tags: java

Here's my code.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    public class Shape{
      private String color;
      private boolean filled;
      
      public setDefault(){
        color = green;
        filled = true;
      }
      
      public Shape(String color, boolean filled){
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
      }
      
      public String getColor(){
        return color;
      }
      public void setColor(String newColor){
        this.color = newColor;
      }
      
      public boolean getFilled(){
        return filled;
      }
      public void setFilled(boolean newFilled){
        this.filled = newFilled;
      }
      
      public void toString(){
        System.out.println("A Shape with color of: " + color + "and" + filled);
      }
    }
    Shape test = new Shape();
    test.toString();
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to make it so that it can print "A shape with color of green and filled. Here are my errors.

```
exit status 1
Main.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
    public class Shape{
    ^
Main.java:9: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
      public setDefault(){
             ^
```

However I'm quite rusty at Java and I know there's more mistakes. Can someone point out  and tell what the issues are and what I should write to fix it?

Comment: 1. You cannot declare a class inside method -- move the Shape class out of `main` method.  2. If `setDefault()` does not return anything, declare it as `void`:  public void setDefault() {/*...*/}`

Answer (score 1):

First: you're trying to define a class *inside* of a method, that's not allowed (except for anonymous classes).

The simplest fix is to move the class declaration out of the `main` method by moving the start of the `main` method behind your class.

Second: your `setDefault()` method must have a return type. If you don't intend to return anything, use `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a separate class `Shape` and return a `String` in `toString()`. Also, `setDefault` should be a constructor with no arguments:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape test = new Shape();
    System.out.println(test.toString());
  }
}
```

Shape.java:

```
public class Shape{
    private String color;
    private boolean filled;

    public Shape(){
        this.color = "green";
        this.filled = true;
    }

    public Shape(String color, boolean filled){
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        this.color = newColor;
    }

    public boolean getFilled(){
        return filled;
    }
    public void setFilled(boolean newFilled){
        this.filled = newFilled;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "A Shape with color of: " + this.color + " and " + this.filled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1: you are trying to define a Public class inside a method which is not valid: if you want to define a public class then you have to make another file for it by name of `Shape` or if you want to define it inside `Main` class just define it in scope of Main class and you have to access it like: `new Main().new Shape("color", true);`

2: `setDefault()` is a method so its need a return type and if does not return any value you need to make it `void`.

3: Always use **""** (Double Quotation) for string values.

4: you override the default constructor so when you call new you have to pass the parameters for the Shape `new Shape();`:

5: you overridden the `toString()` method and it has a return type of `String` and you have to make it as it defined:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape test = new Shape("color", true);
        System.out.println(test.toString());
    }
}

class Shape {
    private String color;
    private boolean filled;

    public void setDefault() {
        color = "green";
        filled = true;
    }

    public Shape(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String newColor) {
        this.color = newColor;
    }

    public boolean getFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean newFilled) {
        this.filled = newFilled;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "A Shape with color of: " + color + "and" + filled;
    }
}
```